# Limit not evaluating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why is the input `Limit[IntegerPart[Sin[x]/x], x -> 0]` not being evaluated?

[image: Mathematica session]

Comment: No idea. `Limit[IntegerPart[Sinc[x]], x -> 0]` works, though.

Comment: @J.M. The Result is 0 BTW

Comment: ...and if you plot it, you might have an idea why this is so. If you're asking about how to prove it, that's a question for math.SE .

Comment: i know the answer is zero i was just using mathematica to check back...i already asked it on math.se [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145924/difference-in-limits-because-of-greatest-integer-function)

Comment: In general finding `IntegerPart` requires infinite precision, which may be a little much to ask :-). Nevertheless MMA should be able to figure this one out from the series, and in fact it quickly gets the correct answer with, say, `Limit[IntegerPart[Series[Sin[z]/z, {z, 0, 4}]], z -> 0]`. But this is a snare: replacing the `4` with `1` gets a wrong answer. It does not seem to realize that $1+O[z]^2$ can be less than $1$!

Comment: `Limit[IntegerPart[Sin[x]/x], x -> 10^-80]` returns 0, so it must be a precision thing.

Comment: @J.M. I get `0` for `Limit[IntegerPart[Sinc[x]], x -> 0]`. Which version are you running? I'm using v8.0.4, but it does the same on v7.

Comment: @whuber the series method does not seem to work on my system.

Comment: @rcollyer: That's what I get as well; the comments at math.SE explain why.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. The non-commutativity of `Limit` and `IntegerPart` is not at all surprising, and was my first thought when I looked at the problem.

Comment: In[1]:= Limit[IntegerPart[Sin[x]/x], x -> 0]
Out[1]= 0
(Coming in version 9.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Time traveling comments and answers are banned outside a tachion field :). Are WR updating Mma for symbolic manipulation of `IntegerPart[]`? That would be great!

Comment: @belisarius I don't think there was a general update of that sort. (Checking my notes...) Series had some modest changes a few months back that were intended to handle Limit examples of the type seen in this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A closely related problem was treated in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326110/a-curious-plot-with-integerpartx) I asked some time ago that received a beautiful answer from @acl.

The documentation for `IntegerPart[]` says:

> Mathematical function, suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation.

Nevertheless, the symbolic part of the assertion has been proved false in the aforementioned question. Just take a look at what Mma *thinks* of its derivative:

[image]

So, What does `Limit[]` do when a non-symbolically treatable function is given as an argument? Let's try it:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Sin[x];
Limit[f[x], x -> 8]
(*
  Limit[f[x], x -> 8]
*)
```

**Ha!** it does *nothing*!

That doesn't mean that Mma can't calculate limits for *analytic* non-symbolically treatable functions. It can:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Sin[x];
Limit[f[x], x -> 8, Analytic -> True]
(*
Sin[8]
*)
```

Of course this is useless in your case since `IntegerPart[]` is not analytic.

So, there is a deadlock: Mma does not know how to treat `IntegerPart[]` symbolically, and also doesn't know to calculate limits of functions that are only numerically valued and not analytical.

Sorry :)

## Edit

This is a cheater using PiecewiseExpand:

```
f[x_] := Assuming[ FindMaxValue[Sin[x]/x, x] <= Sin[x]/x <= FindMinValue[Sin[x]/x, x],
                   PiecewiseExpand@IntegerPart[Sin[x]/x]];

Off[FindMaximum::lstol]
Limit[f[x], x -> 0]
On[FindMaximum::lstol]
```

## End Edit